# Help trying to figure out SQL join using PATINDEX or CHARINDEX

Tags: sql

Working on joining up two legacy DB systems into new database where I can avoid silly  problems like what you see below. I am trying to do a join on two tables where the text data is different and it generally works except for instances where the actual full last name wasn't used in the other table. There are other columns that are part of the join but I still need to execute the join on these two columns as well to get the correct results.

```
Table1.Column       Table2.Column
Miller            01 Miller
Grant             1-3 Grant
Rice/Bennet       2A Rice
```

So  (CHARINDEX(table1.column, Table2.Column) > 0) works excpet for when the last name is slighly different like Rice/Bennet <> 02 Rice. 
What is the best way to handle this? generally speaking this type of senario is the only hold up.

UPDATE : I was thinking that perhaps an easier way would be to replace any numbers and characters up to the first space in table2.column and use that against table1.column  ?? I found in previous years that the first couple of characters could be numbers or letters but that there was a space before the start of the last name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the update to your question if you want to trim off the first few characters including the space in the 2nd column and compare that to the 1st column like you described then this is what you can stick down in your WHERE clause.

(CHARINDEX(RIGHT(table2.column, len(table2.column)-CHARINDEX(' ', table2.column)), table1.column) > 0)

Answer (score 0):

You have them the wrong way around:

```
select charindex('bcd','abcde')
```

gives 2

```
select charindex('abcde','bcd')
```

gives 0

Rob

Comment: flipped around my columns and now I get no results, probably because of the '01','02','03' which are the first three characters (including the space) before the start of the last name

Comment: Oh, sorry... I had read that as being a separate field. You could use: charindex(stuff(t2.column,1,charindex(' ',t2.column),''),t1.column) - but I would recommend storing your data differently, so that you can help it with indexes.

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter of CHARINDEX (or PATINDEX) must be a substring of the second parameter.  Neither function is smart enough to match on a specific portion of the substring.  'Rice/Bennet' can't be found in '02 Rice'.  Examples:

```
CHARINDEX('Miller', '01 Miller') = 4
CHARINDEX('Grant', '03 Grant') = 4
CHARINDEX('Rice/Bennet', '02 Rice') = 0
```

In order to make the query work, you'd need to construct an inline view where you parse the Table1.Column value to deal with these situations.  CHARINDEX/PATINDEX tells us you're using SQL Server - if it is 2005+, you can use Common Table Expressions (CTEs).

```
JOIN (SELECT CASE
               WHEN CHARINDEX('/', t.column) > 0 THEN
                 SUBSTRING(t.column, 0, CHARINDEX('/', t.column)-1)
               ELSE
                 t.column
             END AS column
        FROM TABLE1 t) t1 ON CHARINDEX(t1.column, Table2.column) > 0
```

Mind that in the example, 'Bennet' wouldn't ever be used to check for a corresponding entry in Table2.

Comment: And unfortunately I am working on migrating these "2000" Db's to one SQL 2005/2008 database, depending on what I can get my boss to buy.

Comment: Nothing wrong with either, just glad I provided the inline view example rather than a CTE =)

Comment: I am having a hard time getting that into my already crazy join, do you think I could just do somethign in the where clause based on my question updat ( using a reg expression on table2.column and just charindex that value on the full last name in table1.column?

Comment: Sorry, no.  Update the question with what is complicating the join, I'll take a shot at it.

Comment: I'm just getting way to many records back, the join is creating more records than there should be.

Comment: I'm not sure how much help we'll be here if you don't provide more detail.  You'd need a function that supports regex in order to filter Table2.column values, which does exist until you're using SS 2008 as I understand.

Comment: I see what you mean by the regex. I'll play around with your solution for a while. Thanks for your help so far!